# Is there a way to unmount a "parent" mount point?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

A colleague of mine mounted an incorrect volume onto the directory, and then mounted the correct volume onto the same directory. Is there a way to unmount this "incorrect" volume without touching the "correct" volume?

Here's a reproducible example of this situation:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file-a bs=1M count=1
$ mkfs.ext4 file-a
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file-b bs=1M count=1
$ mkfs.ext4 file-b
$ mkdir target
$ sudo mount -o loop file-a target
$ sudo mount -o loop file-b target
```

Here's the situation after these commands:

```
$ findmnt
TARGET                                SOURCE         FSTYPE         OPTIONS
/                                     /dev/xxx       ext4           
└─/home/user/test-umount/target       /dev/loop1     ext4           rw,relatime
  └─/home/user/test-umount/target     /dev/loop2     ext4           rw,relatime
```

So we want to unmount the `/dev/loop1` device here, but keep the `/dev/loop2` mounted onto `target`.

Doing `umount target` will unmount the second volume, which is not the intended effect. Trying to umount the loop device itself gives:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/loop1
$ umount: /dev/loop1: umount failed: Invalid argument.
```

Is there some way to solve this conundrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Move that `target` mount elsewhere, unmount the original, and then move it back:

```
# mkdir target-1
# mount --move target target-1
# umount target
# mount --move target-1 target
```

---

If the root or any other parent mounts of `target` have their propagation set to shared (the default when using systemd), a move mount will not work. In that case, you could bracket the `mount --move` by a pair of `mount --make-rprivate /; ...; make --rshared /` commands:

```
# mkdir target-1
# mount --make-rprivate /; mount --move target target-1; mount --make-rshared /
# umount target
# mount --make-rprivate /; mount --move target-1 target; mount --make-rshared /
```

It's a good idea to check that, though. Before and afterwards:

```
# grep -v shared /proc/self/mountinfo
#
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - I get "bad option; moving a mount residing under a shared mount is unsupported" when trying to do "mount --move target target-1".

Comment: I'm using Linux 5.14.9-arch2-1, if that matters.

Comment: the shared error is about having `/home` or `/` mounted shared by systemd on boot. It has to be turned off with `mount --make-private`

Comment: @A.B - If I use `--make-private`, then I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock, missing codepage or helper program, or other error" when trying to move afterwards. Tried using --make-private on both `/` and `target`. And findmnt shows that the "shadowed" target is still "shared".

Comment: Solved it! Had to use `mount --make-rprivate /` to recursively set all mounts to "private" propagation type, and that included the shadowed mount as well.